# How to add Case records into hash map with Property Id as key

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

I want to add case records into HashMap i want to keep property id as key and value as cases associated with the property  .

```
   List<Case> eFileQuery = new List<Case>();
    
    eFileQuery  =[Select Id, CaseNumber,PropertyCase__c from Case Where Property_Staff_Name__c =: contactId];
```

I want to add the  Case records into hashMap because i want to update the case records base on the property value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming PropertyCase__c is the property Id, you can do something like this:

```
    Map<Id,List<Case>> casesPerProperty = new Map<Id,List<Case>>() // key -> property Id, value -> List of cases associated to property
    for(Case thisCase : [Select Id, CaseNumber,PropertyCase__c from Case Where Property_Staff_Name__c =: contactId]){
      if(!casesPerProperty.containsKey(thisCase.PropertyCase__c)){
        casesPerProperty.put(thisCase.PropertyCase__c,new List<Case>());
      }
      casesPerProperty.get(thisCase.PropertyCase__c).add(thisCase);    
    }
```

here we have created a map with id as a key and value as list to store all the cases, now looping over all the desired cases first check if case id is there in the Map, if not then add a key for the property id and put an empty list to store the cases and then add the current case.

Answer (score 2):

Apex includes a native feature that allows you to achieve what you want in a single line of code. All you have to do is instantiate a new map with your query as parameter.

```
Map<Id, Case> casesById = new Map<Id, Case>([Select Id, CaseNumber,PropertyCase__c from Case Where Property_Staff_Name__c =: contactId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a map if <id,case>

```
Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id,Case>();
```

loop over your case list, as soon as you find your case record to be mapped with a *property id* .put(propertyid, case record) to add a new key,value pair to your map.

As it's a lil unclear by the ques, I am assuming you can retrieve the property Id, associated with the case record in the same SOQL query.

```
   for(Case c : <*caselist*>){
        caseMap.put(<*c.property_Id__c*>, c);
    }
```

If what I assumed is wrong, please mention in the comment.

> edit after comment

create a map of (id, List) check for the id in the map if not present at first put the id and an empty list of case in the map, then retrieve the id(key) from the map and add the record inside the List associated to it.

```
 Map<id,List<case>> caseMap = new Map<id,List<case>> ();
    
    for(Case c : <*caselist*>){
        
        if (!caseMap.containsKey(c.<*property id*>) {
            List<Case> entitiesForKey = new List<Case>();
            caseMap .put(c.<*property id*>, entitiesForKey);
        }
     caseMap.get(c.<*property id*>).add(c);

    }
```

I hope this will help.

Cheers

Comment: I want to differentiate each record with their property id so want property id as key and caserecord as value . May be there are multiple case record associated with single property so how to add those in map please tell me

Comment: please check the edited the answer.. this will help.